# Multiple monitors and handles

Tags: c++, resolution, gdi, monitors

Trying to run a for loop through physical monitors but the handles are really confusing me, I have pseudo code that runs along the lines of:

```
int tempCounter=0
for(counter = number of monitors;counter > 0;counter--){

    RECT tempRECT;
    HDC tempHDC;

    Get resolution of DC handle (counter) -> tempRECT;
    arrayList[tempCounter] = tempRECT;
    Get virtual work area of DC handle (counter) -> tempRECT;
    arrayList[tempCounter++] = tempRECT;
    tempCounter++;
}
```

GetSystemMetrics(80) for the count of monitors, is this reliable enough to use, or any exceptions it might fail?

I know there is not much there, but looking on the MSDN just kept me going around in circles, that and I am not very competent at programming.

Comment: Your actual code is supposedly wrong, pseudo code does not show the problem. [`EnumDisplayMonitors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610) is how you enumerate the monitors (without a counter).

Comment: I do realise I need to use EnumDisplayMonitors, but that has more than confused me. The MSDN has really confused me about how to do what I want to do. I am not sure either how to get the handle of different monitors.

Comment: You call `EnumDisplayMonitors` and pass your function, which is called for you and receives monitor handles as arguments. Also, [this code snippet shows the usage](http://alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/MonitorInformation/MainDialog.h#L127).

Comment: @BuiltonSin: You know what a callback function is, do you? Because that's the key to using the `EnumDisplayMonitors` function.

Comment: I've seen callbacks but no, I don't know what they are. Perhaps that is why I have been so confused! Thanks so much. *Immediately starts research*

Answer (score 2):

It can be as simple as this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(
    HMONITOR hMonitor,
    HDC hdcMonitor,
    LPRECT lprcMonitor,
    LPARAM dwData
    )
{
    printf("%dx%d\n", lprcMonitor->right, lprcMonitor->bottom);
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {

    EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MonitorEnumProc, 0);
}
```